# How to get back on track after long absence

Tags: practice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get back into an instrument after long break?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/3237/get-back-into-an-instrument-after-long-break)

I have been playing Guitar for more than 8 years now and I was working as a *Electric Guitar Teacher*  while I was Studying at the University, After that I worked as Software Developer and since I could not have the time to play guitar as I used to.

Now I Really want to go back to this talent but I feel like This is the first time I touch a guitar can you advice me or guide me how to get back on track? is there a certain practices I need to do?