# Getting back to the piano after 5 years - restart with lessons or just play?

Tags: piano, learning, exercises

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get back into piano after long break?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/3237/get-back-into-piano-after-long-break)
>   [How to get back on track after long absence](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2745/28)

Before I went to university I spent quite some time playing the piano after several years of lessons, and I dare say I played quite well (for a hobby-pianist). Unfortunately then I lacked both the space for a piano and time for practising, so apart from a few random encounters I have pretty much not played at all.

Now, after about five years, I finally want to start again, and the question is whether by trying to directly play the pieces I played before I risk adapting some bad techniques due to the long lack of practise and should instead consider taking lessons again, or whether it's more like bicycling and I'm likely to get back to my old shape by myself? Or is there a good lessons book that can help me concentrating on refreshing my memories without being too beginner-y?

Comment: There's a [similar question about the guitar](http://music.stackexchange.com/q/2745/3479) the answers to which can be more or less adapted, but it seems to focus strictly on a self-refresher while this question is intended to be open to external resources as well

Comment: Aww, I didn't see [this one](http://music.stackexchange.com/q/3237/3479), now _that_'s really pretty much a dupe...

Comment: The answers to the first are applicable to more than just guitar so I will close this one -- we could certainly expand that question so it's no limited to guitar as well, since I don't think there's a real reason for it to be, and combine it with the piano one.

Comment: @MatthewRead I partially agree - as commented, both of them don't even _consider_ taking lessons again, which is something I'd be interested in as well to hear from others with similar experiences.

Comment: Right.  I think expanding and merging is in order since all the options should be together.  I've done so and expanded my answer a bit, but in the end whether or not you should take lessons should be based on your personal assessment of your situation.  Hopefully the info there helps with that.